# Extract data(both text and images) from Image file

Tags: php, laravel, tesseract, data-extraction, pdf-reader

I have a PDF file(Content as image in PDF), i need to extract text and images from the PDF file. I have tried PDF converter libraries in Laravel, but none is worked. So i have converted that PDF into image with Imagick, after that using TesseractOCR extracting the text from the Image(jpg format), now i need to extract images aslo. Is there any possibility extract both text and image from Image.

My PDF is like below

[image]

I have tried TesseractOCR library in laravel, now i'm able to extract the text successfully.

```
$file = public_path().'/images/S29A57P1-4.jpg';
echo (new TesseractOCR($file))
        ->lang('eng')
        ->run();
```

I want to extract both text and images from PDF or Image.

Comment: Hello anyone is there to guide me?

Comment: Have you solved this problem I am looking for similiar solution?